# aggregate function to concatenate strings in Vertica

Tags: sql, aggregate, vertica

have a table in vertica: test like this:

```
ID     |   name
1      |    AA
2      |    AB
2      |    AC
3      |    AD
3      |    AE
3      |    AF
```

how could I use an aggregate function or how to write a query to get data like this (vertica syntax)?

```
ID    |  ag
1     |  AA
2     |  AB, AC
3     |  AD, AE, AF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll need to compile the udx for `agg_concatenate`.

```
-- Shell commands
cd /opt/vertica/sdk/examples/AggregateFunctions/
g++ -D HAVE_LONG_INT_64 -I /opt/vertica/sdk/include -Wall -shared -Wno-unused-value -fPIC -o Concatenate.so Concatenate.cpp /opt/vertica/sdk/include/Vertica.cpp

-- vsql commands
CREATE LIBRARY AggregateFunctionsConcatenate AS '/opt/vertica/sdk/examples/AggregateFunctions/Concatenate.so';
CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION agg_concatenate AS LANGUAGE 'C++' NAME 'ConcatenateFactory' LIBRARY AggregateFunctionsConcatenate;
```

Then you can do a query like:

```
select id, rtrim(agg_concatenate(name || ', '),', ') ag
from mytable
group by 1
order by 1
```

Uses rtrim to get rid of the last ', '.

If you need the aggregate to be sorted a certain way, you may need to select/sort in an inline view or with first.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Is there a place where I can learn to add the functions generally?  I mean for the command you provide I want to learn so that I can do for other uses next time. Thanks!

Comment: If you look in the `/opt/vertica/sdk/examples` directory, you'll find a lot of other functions. There is also a general make file and a few sql files that show you how to install and test them.

Comment: Could `agg_concatenate` be used with this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55866171/vertica-how-can-you-concate-values-by-some-order)? Where can you download it?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,
    MAX(DECODE(row_number, 1, a.name)) ||
    NVL(MAX(DECODE(row_number, 2, ',' || a.name)), '') ||
    NVL(MAX(DECODE(row_number, 3, ',' || a.name)), '') ||
    NVL(MAX(DECODE(row_number, 4, ',' || a.name)), '') ||
    NVL(MAX(DECODE(row_number, 5, ',' || a.name)), '') ||
    NVL(MAX(DECODE(row_number, 6, ',' || a.name)), '') ||
    NVL(MAX(DECODE(row_number, 7, ',' || a.name)), '') ||
    NVL(MAX(DECODE(row_number, 8, ',' || a.name)), '') ||
    NVL(MAX(DECODE(row_number, 9, ',' || a.name)), '') ||
    NVL(MAX(DECODE(row_number, 10, ',' || a.name)), '')||
    NVL(MAX(DECODE(row_number, 11, ',' || a.name)), '') ||
    NVL(MAX(DECODE(row_number, 12, ',' || a.name)), '') ag
FROM
    (SELECT id, name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) row_number FROM test) a
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.id;
```

Comment: Not the cleanest, but works for issues where I cannot install new code.

Answer (score 1):

The other method is to use `GROUP_CONCAT` from the [strings package on github](https://github.com/vertica/Vertica-Extension-Packages/tree/master/strings_package).

```
select id, group_concat(name) over (partition by id order by name) ag
from mytable
```

However there are some limitations with this method since analytical udx won't allow you to include other aggregates (and you'll have to inline it or use with to add more data to it).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the cleaner way (at least if your Vertica version supports it) is to use the `LISTAGG()` function.

[The LISTAGG function transforms non-null values from a group of rows into a list of values, delimited by a configurable separator, which can be utilized to denormalize rows into a string of comma-separated values or other formats​](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Aggregate/LISTAGG.htm).