# SQL: List/aggregate all items for one corresponding transaction id

Tags: sql, join, concatenation, aggregate, vertica

I have the following table in a vertica db:

```
+-----+------+
| Tid | Item |
+-----+------+
|   1 | A    |
|   1 | B    |
|   1 | C    |
|   2 | B    |
|   2 | D    |
+-----+------+
```

And I want to get this table:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| Tid | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|   1 | A     | B     | C     |
|   2 | B     | D     |       |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
```

Keep in mind that I don't know the maximum item number a transaction_id (Tid) can have, and the amount of items per Tid is not constant. I tried using join and where but could not get it to work properly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no PIVOT ability in Vertica. Columns can not be defined on the fly as part of the query. You have to specify.

There are perhaps other options, such as concatenating them in an aggregate using a UDX, such as what you will find in this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668057/aggregate-function-to-concatenate-strings-in-vertica/39668201#39668201).  But this will put them into a single field.

The only other alternative would be to build the pivot on the client side using something like Python.  Else you have to have a way to generate the column lists for your query.

For my example, I am assuming you are dealing with a unique (Tid, Item) set.  You may need to modify to suite your needs.

First you would need to determine the max number if items you need to support:

```
with Tid_count as (
    select Tid, count(*) cnt
    from mytable
    group by 1
) 
select max(cnt)
from Tid_count;
```

And let's say the most Items you had to support was 4, you would then generate a sql to pivot:

```
with numbered_mytable as (
    select Tid, 
           Item,
           row_number() over (partition by Tid order by Item) rn
    from   mytable
)
select Tid,
       MAX(decode(rn,1,Item)) Item1,
       MAX(decode(rn,2,Item)) Item2,
       MAX(decode(rn,3,Item)) Item3,
       MAX(decode(rn,4,Item)) Item4
from numbered_mytable
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Or if you don't want to generate SQL, but know you'll never have more than X items, you can just create a static form that goes to X.

Comment: This actually works! Thanks a lot. Quick follow up: How would you do the reverse way? The motivation here is, to be able to delete one single row and than transform the table back. This is for Association pattern mining, but for the case were you want a certain Item in your pattern. That way you can delete all transactions that do not include your item.

Comment: If I understand right, for each Item, you would then have to do a union all. Example: `select Tid, Item1 as Item from ... union all select Tid, Item2 from ... union all select Tid, Item3 from ... `.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Create table #table(id int,Value varchar(1))

insert into #table 
select 1,'A'
union
select 1,'B'
union
select 1,'C'
union
select 2,'B'
union 
select 2,'D'
select id,[1] Item1,[2] Item2,[3] Item3 from
(
select id,Dense_rank()over(partition by id order by value)Rnak,Value from #table
)d
Pivot
(Min(value) for Rnak in ([1],[2],[3]))p

drop table #table
```

Comment: Your code is very specific to my example. But my example is only an abstract. In the real case I don't know how many different items there are and what the maximum amount of items is corresponding to one tid.

Comment: There is no `PIVOT` in Vertica. This is a SQL Server answer.