# How to increase Max length of resulting string in UDX function agg_concatenate

Tags: c++, aggregate-functions, vertica

How can I increase the max length of resulting string in agg_concatenate User defined function in Vertica? I have 204 rows with codes like "ABCD" in a column(each code is 4 characters long) which need to be concatenated. But only 162 are in the result.

I tried modifying the Concatenate.cpp file and multiplied input_len * 1000
in line

```
intermediateTypeMetaData.addVarchar(input_len*1000);
```

Then I compiled the new file with name as Concatenate_New.cpp. I followed the commands given in the link below:

[aggregate function to concatenate strings in Vertica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668057/aggregate-function-to-concatenate-strings-in-vertica)

When I run my query, it gives an error like

[Code: 5861, SQL State: VP001]  [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Error calling terminate() in User Function agg_concatenate_new at [Concatenate_new.cpp:91], error code: 0, message: Exception while computing aggregate output: [User code caused Vertica to throw exception "Tried to copy a 1019-byte string to 810-byte VString object; VString is too small"]

So, How do I increase the VString Size?